# Combine 2 replacements into 1

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to perform a 1-step replacement as shown in my example?

I know, groups are used for similar tasks, but I'm not sure they really can work here.

```
var css = `
    .foo { color: green; } // Invalid JS-style comment
    .bar { color: yellow; } // Invalid JS-style comment
    // Standalone invalid comment
    .baz { color: red; } // Invalid JS-style comment
`;

// Is there a way to combine these two replacements in 1 step?
css = css.replace(/;/g, ' !important;');
css = css.replace(/\/\/.*/g, '');

alert(css);
```

Comment: Do you mean other than: `css = css.replace(/;/g, ' !important;').replace(/\/\/.*/g, '');` ?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yes, exactly. Good point. Something different.

Comment: @johnc.j. Why do you need to combine them?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Performance optimization (not sure), easier code maintenance (not sure), self-education.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback function parameter of `replace`, joining the two regexes together using OR `|` (the second regex needs to be grouped in a (preferably) non-capturing group because of `|` priority). Then check if the match is `;` or not:

```
css = css.replace(/;|(?:\/\/.*)/g, function(match) {
    if(match === ";") {
        return " !important;";
    }
    return "";
});
```

Which you can shorten up using an arrow function:

```
css = css.replace(/;|(?:\/\/.*)/g, m => m === ";"? " !important;": "");
```

**Example:**

```js
var css = `
    .foo { color: green; } // Invalid JS-style comment
    .bar { color: yellow; } // Invalid JS-style comment
    // Standalone invalid comment
    .baz { color: red; } // Invalid JS-style comment
`;

css = css.replace(/;|(?:\/\/.*)/g, m => m === ";"? " !important;": "");

console.log(css);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, it works! I will wait some time before approving, to figure out why another answer doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming after the `;` anything that comes is just the close brackets and then comments, just replace everything with what you need:

```
css.replace(/;.*/g, ' !important; }')
```

Of course it won't work if you have multiple statements inside one of the blocks.

Regarding your edit: then you can match the comment and optionally the semi-colon first, but then you will need to use a replace function, like so:

```
css.replace(/(;[^\/]*)?\/\/.*/g, (m, g) => g ? ' !important; }' : '');
```

It matches either just the // or the semicolon and the comment, but captures only the latter. Then, it checks whether something was caught, and replace only on that case.

Comment: Of course, sometimes there will be standalone comments. `// Something` on separate lines. I will edit my question.

Comment: Thanks for edit! However, are you sure there are no mistypes? At first glance all comments preserved: https://jsfiddle.net/99d0wgkw/

Comment: That's because in your fiddle you forgot to re-assign the result of replace to css again (css = css.replace...)

Comment: Don't worry, dude, it's normal to make mistakes! I miss-type things all the time too ;)

Comment: Your second approach [**won't work**](https://jsfiddle.net/b2d5vut6/2/) on multiline css, and it's hard to maintain or change.